# Can a function be homothetic if it's not homogeneous?

Tags: functions

I know that a homogeneous function of positive degree is homothetic, but can a function that is not homogeneous be homothetic?

Comment: What are your definitions of *homogeneous* and *homothetic*? Wikipedia allows a translation in [homothetic transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not know the term in a non-geometric context, so got curious.

If we specialize to two variables, it seems that a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is called *homothetic* if the ratio of the partial derivatives  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ depends only on the ratio of $x$ and $y$.

If that is the case, there are simple examples that show that a homothetic function need not be homogeneous.

For instance, let $f(x,y)=xy +e^{xy}$.  Then
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x +xe^{xy}$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=y +ye^{xy}$$
So their ratio is $x/y$, but $f(x,y)$ is not homogeneous.

A more trivial sort of example is something like $x^7+y^7 +17$, but this could be ruled out by a minor change of definition.